# Multiple Post Requests Occuring in Quick Succession

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This is a bit of an open ended question but we have a problem with a web application that on the final step of completing an order, multiple post requests are being made, sometimes up to 10 and all within a couple of seconds to the page.

Theirs nothing unusual about the page, the user fills out a form which is then validated using the jQuery form validation plugin. We've seen this behavior exhibited over a couple of different browser types, notably IE6 but also IE8.

We've also managed to trigger the bug ourselves but nothing out of the ordinary seems to occur on the browsers end, everything progresses as normal.

Apache logs show that multiple post requests where made at the same time and the Rails logs show that multiple posts requests were also received by the application, leading me to think it's a problem with the browser.

I've exhausted all avenues that I can think of for debugging so I'm throwing this out there to see if anyone has some ideas of what we could try or look for next.

Comment: Might help if you give us examples of the URLs to which it's trying to post (redacted of course).

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to answer without seeing your code, as it is most likely code related. As bad as IE is, I doubt it will make two POST requests unless you tell it to.

My guess at what is happening:

- User fills out the form, presses Enter.
- Your validation plugin validates the page, sends a POST to the server without preventing the original event for triggering.
- This results in the default POST event triggering and the POST via your validation plugin.